# Call an .EXE-Tool with ">" - command inside/as a parameter

Tags: powershell, cmd, command, exe

I would like to call an EXE-Tool (based on Perl) with a PowerShell script.

Basically the following command calls the tool in CMD. The tool processes some files and creates an outfile:

```
tool.exe [OPTIONS] > out.txt
```

Also the tool prints some "results" after creating this outfile.
Now, how can I put this command in a PowerShell environment?

I tried different solutions but always PowerShell itself uses "> out.txt". The tool doesn't get this command and won't be able to create the file correctly:

```
& tool.exe '> out.txt'
```

or with "":

```
& tool.exe "> out.txt"
```

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

```
tool.exe :     1 directories scanned
In ..\Tool_new.ps1:150 Zeichen:1
+ & tool.exe > out.kml
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (    1 directories scanned:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   22 files failed condition
   34 image files read
```

"1 directories scanned" + "22 files failed condition" + "34 image files read" are the results printed.

Comment: Remove your quotes.

Comment: THANKS!
But there'll the next problem: The tool produces some result-outprint after creating the file. And now Powershell interprets these lines as commands --> errors - Do you have an idea?

Comment: Without seeing what your executable is doing, it's hard to speak on what's happening.  All output from an executable in powershell is output as an array of strings.

Comment: The EXE writes some notes, like: "10 files processed, 10 files skipped"

Comment: What are the errors being produced?  Please add them to your question.

Comment: Ah, I tried different scenarios. Finally it seems to be a problem in the ISE. If I run the script in ISE, I get the error (see question post). Without ISE Powershell puts me these results on the host as usual..

Comment: I'd suggest migrating your dev environment from ISE to vscode 

Comment: You may also try save "tool.exe > out.txt" as tool.bat file and then start-process tool.bat in powershell

Comment: Try `cmd.exe /c "tool.exe > out.txt"`

Comment: @RobertCotterman That's working without error in ISE! Thanks!

Comment: it's a good work around, where it uses windows cmd interface to run cmd based executables. Glad it worked! it's not ideal obviously, but it's not bad either. adds maybe a few miliseconds to load cmd.exe on each run.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use:

```
& tool.exe | Out-File -Path '.\out.txt' -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: It was revealed in the comments as an issue with the ISE.

Answer (score 0):

An option to run executables as intended, while in powershell or ISE is to have cmd.exe handle it. This does add a tiny microbit of overhead, and as technology progresses cmd will be phased out. But for the transition period we are in, this is a great option.

An example with your program is...

```
cmd.exe /c "tool.exe > out.txt"
```